# How to use an smarty var inside another var?

Tags: php, smarty, var

I want to get an var in condition with the id of the item in my foreach loop.
What i want to try (just demo code) is as follow but it is just giving me an error.

php

```
$this->smarty->assign(array(
  'demo' => array(
    'foo_bar' => 'succeed!',
    'foo_seat' => 'succeed also!'
  ),
  'bar' => 'bar',
  'seat' => 'seat'
));
```

tpl

```
value="{$demo.foo_{$bar}}"
```

error

```
Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "application/views/overzicht/selectie.tpl" on line 55 "{$demo.foo{$bar}}" - Unexpected "{", expected one of: "}"
```

Who's got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{assign var='property' value='foo_'|cat:$bar}

{$demo.$property}
```

Comment: Sadly, this is taking more resource for each value in the loop. But i guess this is the only option. got it working this way :)